# Loadbalancing script execution on remote machine

Tags: c#, powershell

I have several Powershell scripts that I want to execute on 4 remote machines. I want to do that in a load-balanced way. That is, the application/tool I am looking for (or should build) should schedule 1 script on each of the 4 remote machines and wait. Anytime a machine completes executing a script, it should schedule another script to it for execution. This should continue till all the scripts are executed.

I am willing to use either C# or Powershell to implement this. Can someone please tell if there is an easy way to achieve this? Is there any tool or app already available to be used?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using the term "load balancing" - you just want to run the script on multiple servers

Comment: Agree with @manojlds - look at ultramonkey.org or something. Scripts are different.

Comment: Yes, probably the term "load balancing" is little misleading. The reason I used it was to imply that I want to run the scripts only on machine that is currently idle and has completed the last script execution, thereby balancing the load on the machines. It is not possible to run multiple scripts at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write a simple controller and a windows service.  Install the service on each of your 4 machines, and the controller on your primary machine.

The service should check in with the controller after each completed script execution to see if there is more work to do.  If there is, grab the next script and execute.  If not, go idle and continue checking in every so often.

The design for this type isn't not very complicated.

Comment: Thank you, Chris. I have not written a WCF service before, but I would surely like to write one. Would it be possible for you to please provide a little more details on this?

Comment: @naspras: I wasn't thinking WCF.  Just a regular plain old windows service would suffice.

Comment: Can you please provide me with some more pointers and help? Also, how will the controller look like?